# Trying to do a select where my categories can be all that I have in my categories table

Tags: php, sql

Im trying to do a select in my table posts where my categories can be action, adventure, comedy, scify.

First Im trying to find if there is something like "All" in sql to use in where clause:

```
$where = 'ALL';
$limit = '16';
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category = '$where' ORDER BY visits ASC LIMIT $limit
```

But I dont see any information about, and ALL its not definitely working, so Im trying to write all my categories:

```
$where = 'action OR category = adventure OR category = comedy OR category= scifi';
$limit = '16';
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category = '$where' ORDER BY visits ASC LIMIT $limit
```

But its not working, because I need to use '' in my categories name, but how I can do this in my example?

How can I use  quotes in my categories here:

```
$where = 'action OR category = adventure OR category = comedy OR category= scifi';
```

My full code for this example:

```
if($type == 'action'){
    $limit = '0,3';
    $where = "category = 'action'";
}
else if($type == 'adventure'){
    $limit = '0,5';
    $where = "category = 'adventure'";
}
else if($type == 'comedy'){
    $limit = '0,3';
    $where = "category = 'comedy'";
}
else if($type == 'scifi'){
    $where = "category = 'accao' OR category = 'adventure' OR category = 'comedy' OR category = 'scifi'";
    $limit = '16';

}

$posts=
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE '$where' ORDER BY visits ASC LIMIT $limit")
or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You should probably spend some time reading the documentation of you SQL server. It'll take a bit of time, but you'll save a **LOT** more in the future not wasting time inventing completely nonsensical stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you EVERY category, then simply don't define the WHERE. Easy. Also it is not working because you are missing single quotes around every value.

Without defining WHERE you aren't comparing anything, so every row will be returned.

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY visits ASC LIMIT $limit
```

Also, fixed your code if i misunderstood you:

```
$where = "category = 'action' OR category = 'adventure' OR category = 'comedy' OR category= 'scifi'";
$limit = '16';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE $where ORDER BY visits ASC LIMIT $limit";
```

Comment: Thanks, but with your solution Im having an error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'action' OR category= 'adventure' OR category= 'comedy' OR category= 'scifi' at line 1

Comment: I update my question to my full code for this issue Im having, maybe its more easy to see what is happening!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as already mentioned, it doesn't make sense to set a criteria to the query if all possible values are ok.

Secondly, I've added a possible improvement to your code:

```
<?php

$genres = array(
    "action" => "0,3",
    "adventure" => "0,5",
    "comedy" => "0,3",
    "scifi" => "16"
);

$type = "action";

if(!in_array($type, array_keys($genres))) {
    //handle invalid input
}

$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `category` = '%s' LIMIT %s", $type, $genres[$type]);
echo $query;

?>
```

**Last note:** do not use `mysql_*` as they are deprecated. Look into PDO or `mysqli_*`.
If you stick to `mysql_*` functions, which you shouldn't, escape user input with e.g. [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) -- notice the warning.

Good luck!